# how to redirect to when duplicate window open in any web browser ? how to do this requirement like whats app web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In my project from Dashboard, end-users opened webpage links multiple times by mistake.
how do redirect when the duplicate window opens in any web browser? how to do this requirement like whats app web? using javascript or jQuery?

if I open 2nd time for the same URL or webpage, I need to redirect to the original web page window and de-activate the previous window or webpage.

Comment: Do you have any code at all? What have you tried so far? In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/77422009/edit) and add some code to your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.